# Why cannot upload pictures to Magento media?

Tags: magento, storage, media

I have some problem to upload pictures to magento media storage. As you can see on my attached picture, that feature where I should be able to upload picture, it disappeared. Could it be some update problem or what do you think? Did you have this kind of issues...?

magento media storage
[image: magento media storage]

Comment: What browser are you using? This may just be a problem with how it's handling flash.

Comment: I have tried all kind of browsers, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion / idea?

Comment: In Chrome go to `chrome://settings/content/flash` and add your domain name to the allow list. If your site is example.com then just add `[*.]example.com` to the allow list. After that reload the page and see if it's working then. If it's still not working check the console tab in the chrome developer tools (F12 on the keyboard) and see if there is anything there as far as warnings/errors.

Comment: Charles....you were a huge huge help for me :) Thanks for your help, it works now .....wuhhuuuuu :D

Comment: I'll put an answer in so you can accept it :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome go to `chrome://settings/content/flash` and add your domain name to the allow list. If your site is example.com then just add `[*.]example.com` to the allow list.

[image]

Basically a recent Chrome update (and other browsers are soon to follow with the [deprecation of flash](https://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2017/07/adobe-flash-update.html) being announced) made it so that flash has to be approved prior to running. For some reason the browser doesn't ask first like it's set to, so whitelisting the site should fix the problem.